# Mongoid: Type of timestamps strings?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid

i'm wondering why mongoid is returning a String when i want to read out the created_at date? my problem is: when i want to print the date like this

```
<% @app.created_at.strftime("%m/%d/%y") %>
```

rails is raising a

```
undefined method `getlocal' for "Wed, 11 Jul 2012 02:39:24 -0400":String
```

error. so what can i do to get mongoid to return the date as Time object?

thanks in advance!

Comment: created_at is being set automatically by MongoID. the console tells me, that the created_at class is => ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone

Comment: Show your model definition. Do you have `field :created_at` declaration there?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Does your model contain a

```
include Mongoid::Timestamps
```

If it is, someObject.created_at.class should return Time

See http://mongoid.org/en/mongoid/docs/extras.html#timestamps

Comment: didn't resolve my problem, still getting the same error message